# Can I run Azure Data Studio as another user?

Tags: azure-data-studio

Is there any equivalent to this

```
RUNAS /user:DOMAIN\username "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"
```

in order for me to run ADS as another user?
well, I tried modifying that command and point that to the executable file of ADS but It's not working.

Comment: From the Windows Menu, Azure Data Studio does have the "Run as Different User" option, but it does not work. It does not start the app at all.